# minify/optimization wont change function names angular 12

Tags: angular, minify, angular12

I am currently working on my main project for work and just found out that my prod-build's only minify's the .js content but it doenst changes function or class names.

All my class names and all my properites are keept with the same name.

I have set optimization in angular.json settings but that wont help.

angular.json -> configurations -> production:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss","allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "@babel",
              "canvg"
           ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "7mb",
                  "maximumError": "9mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

[client root files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j18KS.png)

[new project var find in main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mWax.png)

How can i pseudonymise classes and functions?

Comment: Please share your angular.json content

Comment: And also which command are you executing for the production build?

Comment: Please answer all the questions to be able to investigate your issue

Comment: I have added my angular.json to the question and i only use "ng build" to build my prod, i dont use any extra commands or flags

@MehyarSawas

Comment: Tried your angular.json with ng build and could not reproduce. Class names and function names are uglified properly.  I see that you are having the "production" config as the defaultConfiguration which is also fine. only if I run the ng build command on "development" config it keeps the class names. For some reason your angular-cli is not considering the angular.json production config you have. Did you try "ng build -c production"?

Comment: Thanks for your test, i think my angular-cli maybe corrupted. I will keep on trying, if i find anything, i'll post my answer. Note: "ng build -c production" or changing the config-name and then also didn't work, i still can find my functions and class names in the main.js

Comment: do you have a webpack.config.js file in your project root folder?

Comment: i dont have a webpack.config.js file in my root folder (i have added a screenshot of my root files). Do i need one in order for webpack to work?

Comment: No you do not need to. This is just in case you would like to use a custom builder.

Comment: Did you delete the dist folder content before you run ng build -c production ?

Comment: Yes, i did delete the folder before running the command. I also tried setting up a new project ("ng new test-uglify") but also, if i run "ng build" here, the function name's are kept same

Comment: could you show part of your generated bundle file main.js? Where the function name or class name still as it is

Comment: i've added a screenshot, to show what i mean. the function names and property's are the same as in the .ts file

Comment: i just ran "ng new test-uglify" added the function and one var to AppComponent and then run "ng build"

Comment: (my angular/cli version is 12.0.1 what version are you using?) @MehyarSawas

Comment: Sorry! The misunderstanding point here is about naming. After checking your main.js output. Class names are probably uglified in your main.js. What you call functions are methods and methods will not be uglified when optimization is active. Only class names and function names means any function and not class method will be uglified. Properties will be handled the same way as class methods. Since some properties or methods are used in angular html files I do not think this is going to be easy to do.  You can try a webpack custom builder and implement a custom TerserPlugin --mangle-props

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification! I tought angular would also rename classes and methods by default